# Elasticsearch get snapshot size

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

I'm looking for a way to get the storage size of an specific Elasticsearch snapshot? The snapshots are located on a shared filesystem.

It seems there is no API for this?

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the size or status of the elasticsearch snapshot, run snapshot status API [snapshot status API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-snapshot-status-api.html)
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_repository/my_snapshot/_status?pretty"

Note: Mention appropriate values in the above curl.

Sample Output:

```
"snapshots" : [
{
  "snapshot" : "index-01",
  "repository" : "my_repository",
  "uuid" : "OKHNDHSKENGHLEWNALWEERTJNS",
  "state" : "SUCCESS",
  "include_global_state" : true,
  "shards_stats" : {
    "initializing" : 0,
    "started" : 0,
    "finalizing" : 0,
    "done" : 2,
    "failed" : 0,
    "total" : 2
  },
  "stats" : {
    "incremental" : {
      "file_count" : 149,
      "size_in_bytes" : 8229187919
    },
    "total" : {
      "file_count" : 463,
      "size_in_bytes" : 169401330819
    },
    "start_time_in_millis" : 1631622333285,
    "time_in_millis" : 208851,
    "number_of_files" : 149,
    "processed_files" : 149,
    "total_size_in_bytes" : 8229187919,
    "processed_size_in_bytes" : 8229187919
  },
  "indices" : {
    "graylog_130" : {
      "shards_stats" : {
        "initializing" : 0,
        "started" : 0,
        "finalizing" : 0,
        "done" : 2,
        "failed" : 0,
        "total" : 2
      },
      "stats" : {
        "incremental" : {
          "file_count" : 149,
          "size_in_bytes" : 8229187919
        },
        "total" : {
          "file_count" : 463,
          "size_in_bytes" : 169401330819
        },
        "start_time_in_millis" : 1631622333285,
        "time_in_millis" : 208851,
        "number_of_files" : 149,
        "processed_files" : 149,
        "total_size_in_bytes" : 8229187919,
        "processed_size_in_bytes" : 8229187919
      },
      "shards" : {
        "0" : {
          "stage" : "DONE",
          "stats" : {
            "incremental" : {
              "file_count" : 97,
              "size_in_bytes" : 1807163337
            },
            "total" : {
              "file_count" : 271,
              "size_in_bytes" : 84885391182
            },
            "start_time_in_millis" : 1631622334048,
            "time_in_millis" : 49607,
            "number_of_files" : 97,
            "processed_files" : 97,
            "total_size_in_bytes" : 1807163337,
            "processed_size_in_bytes" : 1807163337
          }
        },
        "1" : {
          "stage" : "DONE",
          "stats" : {
            "incremental" : {
              "file_count" : 52,
              "size_in_bytes" : 6422024582
            },
            "total" : {
              "file_count" : 192,
              "size_in_bytes" : 84515939637
            },
            "start_time_in_millis" : 1631622333285,
            "time_in_millis" : 208851,
            "number_of_files" : 52,
            "processed_files" : 52,
            "total_size_in_bytes" : 6422024582,
            "processed_size_in_bytes" : 6422024582
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In the above output, look for

```
"total" : {
      "file_count" : 463,
      "size_in_bytes" : 169401330819
    }
```

Now convert size_in_bytes to GB, you will get the exact size of the snapshot in GB's [Convert bytes to GB](https://www.google.com/search?q=bytes%20to%20gb&oq=bytes%20to&aqs=chrome.0.0i131i433i512j0i433i512j69i57j0i433i512j0i512l2j0i433i512j0i512l3.2281j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

You could get storage used by index using [_cat API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) ( primary store size). First snapshot should be around index size.

For Incremental snapshots, it depends . This is because snapshots are taken in a segment level ( index-.. ) so it may be much smaller depending your indexing. Merges could cause new segments to form etc..

https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-snapshot-and-restore Gives a nice overview

Answer (score 0):

I need an exact solution of the used size on the storage.

Now I use the following approach: separate directories on index/snapshot level and so I can get the used storage size on system level (du command) for a specific index or snapshot.